# I want to show / hide rows with macros in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

/* What I want with this code using macros is to hide and show multiple columns BUT with the same button. However, it does not give the expected results. I need your help.
*/

```
function Show_Hide() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var status = 1;

  function Show() {
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getColumnGroup(3, 1).expand();
    status = 1;
  };

  function Hide() {
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getColumnGroup(3, 1).collapse();
    status = 0;
  };

  if (status==1){
    Hide();
  } else{
    Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What are the expected results? The code using the column grouping feature rather than the hiding feature? Are you looking for help about collapsing / expanding groups or for hiding columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code is that you are setting `status` to `1`, and then checking if it is equal to `1`. (It will always equal `1` with this logic).

Instead,

### Show/Hide Grouped Columns:

```
function ShowHide() {

  const targetGroup = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
                                    .getActiveSheet()
                                    .getColumnGroup(3, 1)

  return (targetGroup.isCollapsed())
  ? targetGroup.expand()
  : targetGroup.collapse()

}
```

This will check if the specified column group `.isCollapsed()`, if so it will be expanded, if not it will be collapsed.

**Learn More:**

- [Group.isCollapsed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group#iscollapsed)
- [Ternary (Conditional) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

**Show/Hide Grouped & Non-Grouped Columns:**

```
function ShowHide() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()

  const colStart = 3 // "C"
  const numOfCols = 8 // "C" => "J"

  try {

    if (sheet.getColumnGroup(colStart, 1)) { 

      return (targetGroup.isCollapsed())
      ? targetGroup.expand()
      : targetGroup.collapse()  
      
    }

  } catch (e) {

    return (sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(colStart)) 
    ? sheet.showColumns(colStart, numOfCols) 
    : sheet.hideColumns(colStart, numOfCols)

  }

}
```

Comment: Anytime! Glad it worked out. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: I have another question: What about if I want to show and hide columns if the columns are not grouped? I just want to insert a range for show and hide columns. Example column C to J show and hide with the same button.

Comment: @CesarValarezo The only issue I see is that `grouped columns` only take 1 index, `non-grouped` columns take a start index and a 'number of columns' index. I will attempt to update my post with what I have written.

Comment: @CesarValarezo Updated. Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you, man. I'm new to this area, so I really appreciate it. The code works as I want.

Comment: No worries! Happy to help buddy